# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereRaw()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using old Laravel version 5.2 and I don't want to update it. `whereRaw()` is not working in join case. Is there any fix for `whereRaw()` method for Laravel 5.2?

```
DB::table('employee AS emp')
->rightJoin('attendance AS att','att.employee_id','=','emp.id')
        ->leftJoin('break_punch as bp',function ($bpLeftJoin) use ($prefix){
            $bpLeftJoin->on('bp.attendance_id','=','att.id');
//            $bpLeftJoin->whereNotNull('bp.end');
            $bpLeftJoin->whereRaw('( bp.end AND '.$prefix.'att.start_time >='.$today_startdate_unix.' )');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `DB::raw()` method look like this [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#raw-expressions)

```
DB::table('employee AS emp')
->rightJoin('attendance AS att','att.employee_id','=','emp.id')
        ->leftJoin('break_punch as bp',function ($bpLeftJoin) use ($prefix){
            $bpLeftJoin->on('bp.attendance_id','=','att.id');
//            $bpLeftJoin->whereNotNull('bp.end');
            $bpLeftJoin->where(DB::raw('( bp.end AND '.$prefix.'att.start_time >='.$today_startdate_unix.' )'));
        });
```